# Find the location (x and y index) of values (for example above a limit=0.5) in an 2D array Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, indexing

I want to return the index of elements in a 2d array that fit a certain condition, i.e. >0.5.

Consider the sample 2D array bellow:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[0.720,0.764,0.058,0.101,0.504,0.715,0.373,0.584,0.052,0.617],
              [0.855,0.413,0.952,0.948,0.109,0.397,0.014,0.719,0.896,0.137],
              [0.237,0.660,0.494,0.193,0.504,0.315,0.600,0.172,0.639,0.464],
              [0.534,0.967,0.400,0.400,0.629,0.490,0.580,0.826,0.118,0.023],
              [0.312,0.133,0.335,0.548,0.729,0.687,0.229,0.216,0.759,0.594]])
```

Using the

```
a[np.array(a)>0.7]
```

it is discovered that there are 12 values above 0.7 in the array.

**What should I add to the code so that it can show me the location (or x and y index) of these 12 values??**

for example, in a dataframe like:

| number | value | X index | Y index |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.720 | 0 | 0 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 12 | 0.759 | 4 | 8 |

**I have a huge dataset (21500, 16000) and only 100 values are above my desired limits, so this approach will be very helpfull.**

Answer (score 1):

np.where returns the index of values fitting a specified condition, i.e. >0.5.

```
index = np.where(a>0.7)
```

Returns the index of all values in array a that are larger than 0.7.